# How can I configure Hazelcast nodes to share data on demand?

Tags: hazelcast

I consider using Hazelcast in my project in which I plan to create several nodes which share their data on demand. I mean, each node will store the data in the distributed data structures on their own and when another node try to access the data structure, they will share the inner data.
Is it possible to configure Hazelcast nodes to work like the above?

Comment: Not sure if near-cache solves your issue since I don't really think you understood that in a cluster data is always shared (and there's nothing wrong with that ;-))

Comment: @noctarius , the data is distributed but I think this does not mean that it is always shared.

Comment: Hazelcast creates something that looks like a shared, big heap. It is distributed not replicated and it is always shared as long as nodes are in the same cluster.